# Adobe Reader can't retrieve embedded font from PDF generated with mPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I'm generating PDFs with mPDF v5 and v6.0/6.1, since shortly I've been getting an error from Adobe Reader as soon as I start scrolling in the document:

> The embedded font "MPDFAA+DejaVVuSansCondensed" could not be
>   retrieved. Some charachters might not be displayed or printed
>   correctly.

(Translated from the original german error message)

Also, all umlauts are missing.

This error doesn't occurr in Chrome or in SumatraPDF.

Just to be safe I added ob_clean() before generating the PDF as proposed here, but nothing changed:
[PHP: Adobe Reader can't open PDF files created with mpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276187/php-adobe-reader-cant-open-pdf-files-created-with-mpdf)

Is this mPDF's or Adobe's fault? I've been generating such documents since about 6 months ago, so I guess Adobe rolled out a faulty (?) update?
Is anyone getting the same problem?

Edit: The problem only seem to occur if I use the font "DejaVuSansCondensed" in the constructor, not with "DejaVuSans". Both font files are present in /ttfonts.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround provided by the user asdfa80756749 worked for me.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/8879248

The font files provided by mPDF can't be opened by the latest Acrobat Reader.
As a workaround, the freeware Type Light can be used to open the broken fonts in the ttfonts directory (including their bold etc. versions) and save them again, making them usable by Adobe Reader.